# Автоклик после завершения мелодии

Tags: javascript, html

Я создал аудиоплеер, в котором аудиозаписи "перелистываются" по клику на кнопку. Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка нажималась автоматически после завершения музыкальной композиции.

Comment: `audio.onended = function() {element.click();};`

Comment: спасибо большое)